# How to call Scipy Numba functions on GPU?

Tags: python, scipy, cuda, gpu, numba

After installing the [numba-scipy](https://github.com/numba/numba-scipy) package, the following code snippet works:

```
import numba
import scipy.special as sc

@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64, float64)'])
def t_quantile(df, p):
    return sc.stdtrit(df, p)

t_quantile(2., 0.975)
```

How do I execute `t_quantile()` on the GPU, as I unsuccessfully tried in the following code?

```
import numba
import scipy.special as sc

@numba.vectorize(['float64(float64, float64)'], target='cuda')  # move to GPU here
def t_quantile(df, p):
    return sc.stdtrit(df, p)

t_quantile(2., 0.975)
```

Comment: You can’t. There is no way to run scipy code on the GPU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scipy.special.stdtrit` [is actually not supported](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html) by Numba in nopython mode. Only the fallback implementation can be used (which mostly defeat the purpose of using Numba). In fact, Scipy is mostly unsupported by Numba yet. Thus, you cannot use it in Numba CUDA-targeted functions too. You could try to implement this yourself but this is pretty difficult to do.